# I want to display firebase database in flutter app by using fluttter bloc

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, bloc

this is notes_bloc

```
import 'package:banao_notes/note_f.dart';
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../note.dart';

part 'notes_event.dart';
part 'notes_state.dart';

class NotesBloc extends Bloc<NotesEvent, NotesState> {
   final _database = Firestore.instance.collection('my_collection').snapshots();;
  NotesBloc() : super(NotesInitial()) {
   on<LoadNoteCounter>((event, emit) async {
    try {
        final snapshot = await _database.once();
        final notesData = snapshot;
        final notes = List<Note>.from(notesData?.map((data) => NoteF.fromJson(data)) ?? []);
        emit(NotesLoaded(notes: notes));
      } catch (e) {
        emit(NotesError(message: 'Failed to load notes'));
      }
   },);
   on<AddNotes>((event, emit) async {
    if(state is NotesLoaded){
      final state = this.state as NotesLoaded;
      emit(
        NotesLoaded(notes: List.from(state.notes)..add(event.note))
      );
    }
   },);
   on<RemoveNotes>((event, emit) {
    if(state is NotesLoaded){
      final state = this.state as NotesLoaded;
      emit(
        NotesLoaded(notes: List.from(state.notes)..remove(event.note))
      );
    }
   },);
  }
}
```

this is model class

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class Note{
  String? id;
  String title;
  String content;

  Note({
    this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.content,
  });

  factory Note.fromSnapshot(Map<String, dynamic> snapshot) {
    return Note(
      id: snapshot['id'],
      title: snapshot['title'],
      content: snapshot['content'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'title': title,
      'content': content,
    };
  }

}
```

this is notes class

```
import 'package:banao_notes/add_notes.dart';
import 'package:banao_notes/bloc/notes_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

import 'note.dart';

class NoteScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: BlocBuilder<NotesBloc, NotesState>(builder: (context, state) {
        if(state is NotesInitial){
          return const CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.green,);

        }
        if(state is NotesLoaded){
          return Column(
            children: [
              Text("${state.notes.length}"),
              SizedBox(height: 20,),
              for(int index = 0; index < state.notes.length; index ++)
              Column(
                children: [
                  Text(state.notes[index].title),
                  Text(state.notes[index].content)

                ],
              )
            ],
          );
        }
        else{
          return const Text("something went wrong");
        }
      }
      ,)),
    );

  }
}
```

I want to display firebase database in flutter app by using fluttter bloc. I want to load one time firebase data base put data in bloc and then show it and if user click on add notes then also i have to update firebase database and bloc but then also I want to show data by bloc

Hope you have understand my problem thankyou in advanced!..

I tried to implement it but noting is working

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you are not adding events to the bloc to load notes. Without adding events bloc has no when to do what. You can add `LoadNoteCounter` in the initState method of the widget. Also, use equatable in the state class so the bloc can know when the event has been updated. Here is the code that might help

```
class NoteScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NoteScreenState createState() => _NoteScreenState();
}

class _NoteScreenState extends State<NoteScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Add Event To The Bloc Here
    context.read<NotesBloc>().add(LoadNoteCounter());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: BlocBuilder<NotesBloc, NotesState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is NotesInitial) {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.green);
            }
            if (state is NotesLoaded) {
              return Column(
                children: [
                  Text("${state.notes.length}"),
                  SizedBox(height: 20,),
                  for (int index = 0; index < state.notes.length; index++)
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(state.notes[index].title),
                        Text(state.notes[index].content),
                      ],
                    )
                ],
              );
            } else {
              return const Text("Something went wrong");
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```